# warden is an undefined method issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

An application uses rails 7.0.4 and devise 4.8.  It authenticates as expected in the various controller actions.

However, in testing (Minitest), the assertion of the user being logged_in cannot be reached.

```
require "test_helper"

class ThisKlassControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "should login " do
    sign_in(users(:one))
    assert warden.authenticated?(:user)
  end
```

returns `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'warden' for [...]ControllerTest[...] Did you mean?  warn`  implying the system has no knowledge of warden and the inclusion instruction appears effectively moot.

Given the application is executing authentication, what is clearly missing/wrong in this testing set-up?

Answer (score 0):

The way that Warden works is that it that it lurks near the bottom of the Rack middleware stack and injects itself into `env`. This is just the hash that each Rack middleware passes along to the next layer.

If you really wanted to do this you can access Warden through the request:

```
require "test_helper"

class ThisKlassControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "should login " do
    sign_in(users(:one))
    assert request.env["warden"].authenticated?(:user)
  end
```

But as anything but a sanity test its very smelly. You're poking way too far into the internals here. If you want to test that the user authentication system works do it a higher level and test for example that they can edit their profile.

```
class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "a user should be able to edit their profile" do
    sign_in(users(:one))
    get '/user/edit'
    assert_response :success
  end
```

The Warden test helpers really should just be used sparingly to make your test suite run faster by skipping the steps of actually signing a user in.

Comment: Those eaxt three steps wer the path initially beaten.  I've poken deeper because I was getting `Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>`  thus the authentication is broken in test environment, not development.